# Odoo xmlrpc certification has expired

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, odoo, xml-rpc, erp

I wrote this script around 4 months ago, everything was working fine. But when I returned to this code yesterday  I got the following exception:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)
```

this happens when I run the following:

```
client = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(odoo_server), allow_none=True)
```

what might be the problem?

Comment: Is the server you connect to using a LetsEncrypt certificate with the default 'compatibility' chain including DST Root CA X3 which expired Sept 30 (see numerous other Qs and zillions of blogs) , and does your python use OpenSSL below version 1.1.0? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have to ask the senior for such case. I don't know actually. but when I do I'll tell u. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution might help you out in your situation.

```
import ssl
xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(odoo_server), allow_none=True,verbose=False, use_datetime=True,context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
```

Comment: I tried it and it caused me another error. Plus I don't think it's a good solution for my case since it was working fine

Comment: Ok so after talking to my senior he was ok with this solution. Plus the error that appeared after using this solution was also fixed (credentials were wrong). SO because of that I accepted this answer. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

whats the value in odoo_server, try without http or https. try with your ip or just the domain name

Comment: without http/https or with ip: I get "unsupported XML-RPC protocol"